# Problem with isReachable in InetAddress class

Tags: java, networking, icmp

As an assignment I have to find all the alive computers on a LAN.  For which I am using `isReachable` function of `InetAddress` class.  But problem is that nothing is shown reachable to me. So I tried to have `isReachable` with Google's IP but still this is unreachable.

Here is the code:

```
import java.net.*;

public class alive{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{(byte)209, (byte)85, (byte)153, (byte)104});
            boolean b = ia.isReachable(10000);
            if(b){
                System.out.println("Reachable");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Unrachable");
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Output is : `Unreachable`

Comment: have you tried pinging to the adress?

Comment: do you have root privileges? if not, try w/...

Comment: @pangea ya have tried and it is pinging

Comment: @bestsss ya it was a bit surprising that after having root privileges it was reachable but right after without root privileges it wasn't. why so can you please explain it. thanks

Comment: read the javadoc, it requires such privileges. Basically to use ICMP (raw socket), it does take 'root'. And if you ask why ping from bash doesn't, actually it does need as well. Do that ls -l /bin/ping :)

Comment: hate act like wise guy, but the out put from this code will never be "Unreachable"...but "Unrachable" instead :)

Comment: To clarify, it requires privileges *to use ICMP* (and not Windows). In the other cases it uses TCP to port 7.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some details on why isReachable() might not always work as expected

1. http://bordet.blogspot.com/2006/07/icmp-and-inetaddressisreachable.html
2. http://www.coderanch.com/t/206934/sockets/java/InetAdress-isReachable-Ping-Permissions

The correct way for you is to use the [ICMP](http://www.lincoln.edu/math/rmyrick/ComputerNetworks/InetReference/81.htm) protocol. This is what **ping** uses internatlly, I believe. [Here is an example](http://timofeybasanov.blogspot.com/2007/06/writing-java-icmp-ping-for-windows.html) that get you started.

Comment: The javaranch link contains an error. isReachable() doesn't require that the echo device be actually running. It interprets connection refusal as a success.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code which is platform independent, but requires information about any open port on the other machine (which we have most of the time).

```
private static boolean isReachable(String addr, int openPort, int timeOutMillis) {
    // Any Open port on other machine
    // openPort =  22 - ssh, 80 or 443 - webserver, 25 - mailserver etc.
    try {
        try (Socket soc = new Socket()) {
            soc.connect(new InetSocketAddress(addr, openPort), timeOutMillis);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found interesting solution. If you can't run your aplication as root, you may set raw socket capability on java:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw=ep /usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin/java
```

And then ICMP protocol will be used istead of echo request on 7 TCP port.