# Alternative to isReachable in InetAddress class

Tags: java, networking, icmp

I want to check whether an active internet connection exists or not. For that I [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448666/how-to-do-a-true-java-ping-from-windows) I can do that with the isReachable() method from the InetAddress class. Unfortunately (as the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) suggests and this post [verifies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779367/problem-with-isreachable-in-inetaddress-class)), this only works with root privilegies, what is no solution to my problem.

When I run the following code, isReachable is always false:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("173.194.35.3"); //e.g. google
boolean isReachable = address.isReachable(2000); //ms
```

Therefore, I am searching for a good alternative to check for an active internet connection without the necessity of root privilegies.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be old, but I had the same problem and after read those answers I found this amazing library [icmp 4j](http://www.icmp4j.org/) and solved all my problems. You can download the source code [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/icmp4j/) and use in your project something like this

```
// request
final IcmpPingRequest request = IcmpPingUtil.createIcmpPingRequest ();
request.setHost ("192.168.0.101");

// repeat a few times
for (int count = 1; count <= 4; count ++) {

// delegate
final IcmpPingResponse response = IcmpPingUtil.executePingRequest (request);

// log
final String formattedResponse = IcmpPingUtil.formatResponse (response);
System.out.println (formattedResponse);

// rest
Thread.sleep (1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the [ICMP](http://www.lincoln.edu/math/rmyrick/ComputerNetworks/InetReference/81.htm) protocol? This is what ping uses internally i believe. Check out [this example](http://timofeybasanov.blogspot.co.at/2007/06/writing-java-icmp-ping-for-windows.html). (Allbeit this is is a solution for windows)

Additionally read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402005/how-to-check-if-internet-connection-is-present-in-java) for a high-level discussion on this topic!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I also saw that one, but didn't try it because I have to buy JNIWrapper... So basically, I can chose to buy the Java Native Interface or run my program in root mode (to use theInetAddress.isReachable-code)? Or is there another possibility?

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc doesn't say that at all, and the post you linked doesn't 'verify' it either. What it *actually* says is "A typical implementation will use ICMP ECHO REQUESTs if the privilege can be obtained, otherwise it will try to establish a TCP connection on port 7 (Echo) of the destination host.".

In other words you don't need privileges to call this method at all. You only need privileges *for the ICMP mode.* If you don't have them (or you are on Windows as no ICMP implementation is used), it uses TCP to port 7. And note that it treats either a connection success or a connection refusal as 'reachable'.

Comment: thanks for your post. My java program will run only on Windows machines (so TCP to port 7). Unfortunately, this didn't work on my (Windows-)machine. What should I do now? - Make a firewall exception for port 7 or something like that? Or can the program do something like this on its own? Thank you!

Comment: @casaout Try a different target address that does work. You need one that doesn't just drop port 7 requests on the floor. It has nothing to do with your local box.

Comment: That sounds great. But I didn't find an address/ip that worked... Do you have a suggestion? (I also added the statement I run to the first post. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### InetAddress.isReachable() - can be run without `root`!

You simply need to assign the `java` executable the ability to send ICMP packets/etc.

You do this as follows; *(run as root)*

> setcap cap_net_raw+eip $JAVA_HOME/bin/java

And there you have it... your java app can ping without being root!

---

If you get the following error;

> ./java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

You can fix this with something like; *(needs to be done as root, confirm `/usr/lib64` is correct for you)*

> ln -s $JAVA_HOME/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so /usr/lib64/libjli.so

Please note: unfortunately just doing `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/amd64/jli` doesn't work.